# How do I get the total price?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am doing an online shop using WooCommerce, and I want to get the total price for doing some calculation.

Here is my code for getting the total price with float type.

```
$amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#＄#', '',$order->get_formatted_order_total() ) );
```

[image]

The result is not correct. Can someone help?

Comment: It is work! thank you! And thx for editing my grammar mistake LOL

Comment: be sure to give that guy an upvote when you have the rep :)